# Calling REST service to POST image with selected(croped)parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, backbone.js, jax-rs

I am taking file as a input.On that file I applied crop tool that gives me co-ordinates x1,x2,y1,y2. I want to send this data to my Rest service(JAX-RS).I am new to clien side programming.
My html code is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img#blah').imgAreaSelect({
    handles: false,
    maxWidth: 145,
    minWidth: 145,
    maxHeight: 190,
    minHeight: 190,
    onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
    console.log('here '+selection.x1);
    console.log('here '+img.valueOf());
        }
    });
});
</script>

<form action="rest/file/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" name="uploadedFile"/>
    <div style="height: 250px"><img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" style="max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%"/></div>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
</form>
```

I want to call service `http://localhost:8080/app/test` with parameters i.e. x1,x2,y1,y2 with image. how i can achive this?

Comment: Where is Backbone.js here involved?

Comment: @Pugcerber I am looking for simplest way to do that. May be Backbone.js is option.I can send only file using multipart to server.Its working fine but I want to send some parameters(x1,x2,y1,y2) with it..

Comment: Create new inputs in your form and assign x1,x2,y1,y2 values to them in your `onSelectEnd` function.